# How to create a service mock implementation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am quite on new Laravel I am trying to create some mock services.

If I will send a request to some URL :`http:/example.com?token={token}`. It will return user data if I have token access. The case is that I don't have token access and I cannot get user data. Now I want to create mock service to get user data when I don't have a token and save data on the database.

For example, I have CSV fill user data like this:

```
   *----*-------*-------------*---------------*
   | Id |  Name | phoneNumber |  dateOfBirth  |
   *----*-------*-------------*---------------*
   | #1 | test1 |   1234      |  12-12-2001   |
   | #2 | test1 |   12345     |  12-12-2005   |
   *----*-------*-------------*---------------*
```

when I am sending request to my laravel application then I want to create service-mock implementation with the service interface. My mock service adapter now should user above csv data and store data in the database.

I am not getting how I can create this type of mock service on laravel. Anyone, will you please give me some idea of how I can do the implementation.

It would really help if some get some ideas for implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel comes with a feature called model factories that are designed to allow you to quickly build out “fake” models (dummy data) which probably what you're looking for.

These have several use cases with the two biggest being–testing (mocking) and database seeding.

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database-testing#using-factories)

Comment: I think you mis understood my question. Actually I want to create a import service from certain url like `http:/example.com?token={token}`. Now If I don't have  access to this url then I want to create a service mock Implementation where my service mock should import data from CSV file .

Answer (score 0):

I think php-vcr (https://github.com/php-vcr/php-vcr) can be used in this case.